# Bootstrap tabs activate on footer menu item click (WordPress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

i have bootstrap tabs

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="menu-services">
  <!-- Nav tabs --><p></p>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation"><a href="#front" aria-controls="front" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><br>
    </a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#back" aria-controls="back" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><br>
    </a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#management" aria-controls="management" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><br>
    </a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#speciality" aria-controls="speciality" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><br>
    </a></li>
</ul>
<p>  <!-- Tab panes --></p>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="front">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="back">
......
</div>
```

That works perfect (click on tab-activate it), but now i have footer menu items in WordPress which also need to activate tabs on click.

For example : First menu item on click activates first tab etc .
I tried so many solutions from this forum, but nothing works .
I need a jQuery script and example how to format  tag in footer menu li item which will work well in my case.

Comment: Show us what you already tried, or provide a fiddle

Comment: You can use javascript to activate tabs [bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage)

Answer (score 0):

when using javascript, you want to capture the onclick of what ever you want to trigger the tab switch in your footer.

then following the documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage) you can activate the tabs by name or index.

i set up a fiddle using this method to activate tabs:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')
```

fiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/mudpuddle/o74qhbwc/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foot').click(function(){
    $('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').tab('show')
  });
});
```

Comment: Why am I getting message $('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').tab('show')  : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ?

Comment: I alerted $('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').html() and saw that selector did its job correct! But when I add $('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').tab('show') it throws error

Comment: I added this part of code to footer oh my php template.
<script>$('.foot').click(function(){
    $('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').tab('show')
});
 </script>

Comment: That bit of code needs to be run onDocumentReady, see if that helps.  And what is the error?

Comment: I am beginner at jQuerry so can you explain me what  onDocumentReady mean? Can you give me example with my piece of code.
$('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').tab('show') : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: In the fiddle, `$('.foot').click` adds the click function to every thing with the `class='foot'`.  This can't be done until the page is drawn and ready, so jQuery gives you the `$(document).ready(function() {})` function to add functionality once the page is ready.  I edited the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to view the problem
http://staffing911.com/beta/services/

Below main services there is a list named Outer links.
Click on them need to activate tabs above.
But, when clicked, console Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on

```
$('#myTab a[href="#' + $(this).text() + '"]').tab('show')
```

Comment: looking at your code, it looks like you add that `.tab('show')` to the main buttons to control your tabs, but not the list items in the footer.  If you add that .proba class to the li items in your footer, I think you can get rid of the links in your footer and have just the list items.  Might want to try wrapping your `$('.proba').click...` code with the document ready.  take a look at my original answer.